# How to validate length of query chosen multi-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, multi-select

I'm working on the validation part of the jQuery Chosen multi-select. Validation is working fine and I want to allow only one option in the multi-select dropdown. I am trying to get the `length` of the multi-select but it's not working. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Note, when I click on the 'save' button I want show an `alert` like 'please select only one option'.

Also, multi-select has lot of options but my scenario here is if the drop-down is holding more than one option it should throw the 'select one option only' error, as above.

```js
 $(".chosen-select").chosen(); 
document.getElementById("plvalidate").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  $("#error_sp_msg_pg, #error_sp_msg_soi, #error_sp_msg_cpsea, #error_sp_msg_cpstag, #error_sp_msg_cpvari").remove();
  var soilone = document.getElementById("soilval").value;
  var cpseason = document.getElementById("seasonval").value;
  var cpstages = document.getElementById("stagval").value;

  if (soilone == "" || soilone == null) {
    //alert("Please select atleset one soil type");
    $(
      "<span/>", {
        "id": "error_sp_msg_soi",
        "html": "Please select atleset one soil type"
      }).insertBefore($("#soilval"));
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  if (cpseason == "" || cpseason == null) {
    //alert("Please select atleset one season");
    $("<span/>", {
      "id": "error_sp_msg_cpsea",
      "html": "Please select season"
    }).insertBefore($("#seasonval"));
    event.preventDefault();
  } else if (cpseason.lenght > 1) {
    alert('please select only one option');
    $("<span/>", {
      "id": "error_sp_msg_cpsea1",
      "html": "Please select only one season"
    }).insertBefore($("#seasonval"));
  }

  if (cpstages == "" || cpstages == null) {
    //alert(""Please select atleset one stage");
    $("<span/>", {
      "id": "error_sp_msg_cpstag",
      "html": "Please select atleset one stage"
    }).insertBefore($("#stagval"));
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

Test :
<select id="soilval" data-placeholder="Select Soil type" class="chosen-select form-control" multiple tabindex="1">
  <option>test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
  <option>test3</option>
</select>

Test2:
<select id="seasonval" data-placeholder="Select Season" class="chosen-select form-control" multiple tabindex="1">
  <option>Test3</option>
  <option>Test4</option>
  <option>Test5</option>
</select>

Test3
<select id="stagval" data-placeholder="Select Stages" class="chosen-select form-control" multiple tabindex="1">
  <option>Test5</option>
  <option>Test6</option>
  <option>Test7</option>
</select>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="plvalidate">Save</button>
```

Comment: `I want allow only one option in multi-select-dropdown` Then why use a multi select at all...?

Comment: Also, you state you're using Chosen, and I can see you reference the library, but it's never instantiated on your `select` elements. Are you sure it's relevant to this code block?

Comment: Yes. this is different scenario actually some times I have to use multiple options in drop-down but in my project I have to control few drop-downs not having more then one option please help.

Comment: for example- if i have 10 dropdowns I want allow more then option for a few drop-downs and some more dropdowns i have to allow only one option please try to understand In case when i click on save button I want to show the error message like please select only option for this dropdown

Comment: I still don't see why you'd use a multi-select in that case.

Comment: that is project dependency I can't explain that all now. but As per my concept i want to show the alert when multi-select have more then one option could you please help me on that.

Comment: Rory McCrossan Do you know Answer?

Comment: @ChinniCh, Do you want like this https://jsfiddle.net/es1gpjtn/?

Comment: @Vel Thank you! But when I selected more then one option in  Test2 dropdown at that time i want to show the alert like Please select only one option For example: test1, test3 dropdowns satisfied with one or two that's not a problem but test2 dropdown should allow only one option in dropdown. Please make changes in code .and thank you for your help.

Comment: Please check this update fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/jry4ebz6/

Comment: I just noticed in the lines of code where it shows "cpseason.lenght > 1" a typo of "length" which can be corrected. This could also be one reason for the issues.

Comment: @Vel thank you for effort/help its working fine .but test2 dropdown error message is still it visible even when that dropdown is satisfied with option could you please have look on it. I'm expecting when test2 drop-down is satisfied with one option error message should remove from that dropdown

Comment: @ChinniCh, Please check my updated answer

Comment: @Vel it's working fine in js fiddle .but when i execute this in my workspace it's still showing error message even I added $("#error_sp_msg_cpsea1").remove(); what is the reason might be.

Comment: @ChinniCh, Not sure. Please create fiddle with your code. SO I can check.

Comment: @Vel Ok I will create that in fiddle.

Comment: @Vel I just added my code in fiddle please have a look on that. https://jsfiddle.net/qpyox8h2/8/

Comment: @Vel have you seen that?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fbk6m42p/

Comment: use `$("#soilval").val();` instead of `document.getElementById`

Comment: @Vel It's a Great help my dear. I thank you really a lot. it's working awesome. and May I know your email ID

Comment: Glad to help you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated code.**

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen();

document.getElementById("plvalidate").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    $("#error_sp_msg_pg, #error_sp_msg_soi, #error_sp_msg_cpsea, #error_sp_msg_cpstag, #error_sp_msg_cpvari").remove();
    var soilone = $("#soilval").val();
    var cpseason = $("#seasonval").val();
    var cpstages = $("#stagval").val();
    console.log("soilone11", soilone);
    if (soilone == "" || soilone == null) {
        alert("Please select atleset one soil type");
        $(
            "<span/>", {
                "id": "error_sp_msg_soi",
                "html": "Please select atleset one soil type"
            }).insertBefore($("#soilval"));

    }
    $("#error_sp_msg_cpsea1").remove();
    if (cpseason == "" || cpseason == null) {
        //alert("Please select atleset one season");
        $("<span/>", {
            "id": "error_sp_msg_cpsea",
            "html": "Please select season"
        }).insertBefore($("#seasonval"));
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (cpseason.length > 1) {
        alert('please select only one option');
        $("<span/>", {
            "id": "error_sp_msg_cpsea1",
            "html": "Please select only one season"
        }).insertBefore($("#seasonval"));
    }

    if (cpstages == "" || cpstages == null) {
        //alert(""Please select atleset one stage");
        $("<span/>", {
            "id": "error_sp_msg_cpstag",
            "html": "Please select atleset one stage"
        }).insertBefore($("#stagval"));
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```